# how to change the title color and image tint color of UIContextualAction button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I want to change the title and Image tint color of  button but I am not able to do that.
there are no such properties or methods to change.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
    {

 let discardButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "DISCARD", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("discardButton action ...")
            success(true)
        })
        discardButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
       
        discardButton.backgroundColor = .red


        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [discardButton])
    }
```

I want to change the text color and image tint color.

Shell we overlap the button to UITAbleView Cell like this image

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588716/1801544 ? Use a custom view for it?

Comment: Can we overlap the Swip button and Cell